# Using the Facebook long lived token

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've been battling for a few hours with the problem of using the Facebook long lived token in my current Session for Facebook requests.

The application's flow is as follows:
1) The user launches the Android app and clicks on the 'log in with Facebook' button
2) The user is redirected to Facebook where they provide access to certain parts of their account (friends list, email etc.)
3) The user is then redirected back to my app which (if successful) finds the Session object is opened and I retrieve (amongst other info) a short term access token.
4) I pass this short term access token to my server application which does another call to Facebook to swap the short term token for a long lived token, which my server application returns to my app.

After I receive the long term access token, how do I 'use it' or modify my existing Session (Session.getActiveSession()) such that long lived access token is used in subsequent requests to Facebook and thus remain valid for (I believe) 60 days?

I'm currently using the latest version of the Android SDK.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#class_methods I can see that there's a

`openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(Context, AccessToken, StatusCallback)` method.

Description:

> Opens a session based on an existing Facebook access token, and also
>   makes this session the currently active session. This method should be
>   used only in instances where an application has previously obtained an
>   access token and wishes to import it into the
>   Session/TokenCachingStrategy-based session-management system. A
>   primary example would be an application which previously did not use
>   the Facebook SDK for Android and implemented its own
>   session-management scheme, but wishes to implement an upgrade path for
>   existing users so they do not need to log in again when upgrading to a
>   version of the app that uses the SDK. In general, this method will be
>   called only once, when the app detects that it has been upgraded --
>   after that, the usual Session lifecycle methods should be used to
>   manage the session and its associated token.
>
> No validation is done that the token, token source, or permissions are
>   actually valid. It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that these
>   accurately reflect the state of the token that has been passed in, or
>   calls to the Facebook API may fail.

Have you tried this?

Comment: Hi Tobi, I have tried that. I first tried closing the session first and then calling that method - this resulted in an error. I then tried not closing the session then calling the 'openActiveSessionWithAccessToken' method and this actually closed the session. I'm going to try this again and get the exact error message to post. Thanks for your reply though!